# Viewing a PDF file from database

Tags: asp.net, pdf, gridview

I'm having an issue that I cannot seem to solve. I'm trying to view a PDF file from a GridView. When I click my linkbutton (View) it should display the PDF file below the GridView. I am getting the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The error shows on the line of code:

```
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
```

This line of code is in my Button2_Click which is linked to my Linkbutton. I got most of my information on how to do this from another article, found [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-and-display-PDF-Files-from-database-in-browser-in-ASPNet.aspx)

How do I go about fixing the PDF file showing on my form?

Comment: `CommandArgument` is not being correctly parse as an `int`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in `(sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument` is being parse as an `int`

```
var arg = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
if(arg !=null) {
    int id = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(arg.Tostring(), out id) && id != 0) {
        //Do what you intended
    }
}
```

Quote from article:

> Displaying PDF file from Database Table using the View Button in
>   GridView The below event handler is raised when the View LinkButton is
>   clicked inside the GridView Row. Here I am making use of HTML OBJECT
>   Tag to embed PDF in browser. An HTML string of an OBJECT tag is
>   generated in which the ID (determined using the CommandArgument
>   property of the LinkButton) is passed to the Generic Handler which
>   will read the file from database and pass it to the OBJECT tag. The
>   HTML string is then set to the Literal Tag.

Are you sure you are setting the `CommandArgument` of the `LinkButton`?

If you look at the markup form the article you will see where they set the `CommandArgument`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I have this in my View:
            string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"600px\">";
            embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
            embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
            embed += "</object>";
          
            ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);

Comment: I even made a new project with that code from the article, everything works except when I click on the view, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Yes, sorry I do have that:

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Actually, I can't even get the Upload to work now. :(